# Problem with concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I made a function that given a list with links with different images, they download them. To speed up this process I used threads. This is what I wrote:

```py
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(self .__descargar_imagen__, self.links_paginas)
```

Here `__descargar_imagen__` is a function that downloads the images and links_paginas is the list with all the links. The problem is that for some reason, with that code, the program does not wait for all threads to finish, so it downloads only part of the images. Is there a way to make the program wait until all threads are terminated with concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor?

Answer (score 0):

Using multiprocessing.pool:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
checker = ThreadPool(processes).imap_unordered(downloader_function, url_list)
for foo in checker:
    print(foo)
```

where, "processes" is the number of processes you'd like to run.
You could use the cpu_count() function in os/multiprocessing to get the maximum number of processes you can run on a given system.